# ASP.NET Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint - Docker & Linux

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, certificate, haproxy

I'm having an issue with my docker images, a month ago they worked well but I have done a minor change (HTML change, in a minor page) and try to rebuild a new docker image.

But when I deploy the docker image, I got the following error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
```

Here is a summary of the setup

[image]

I tried to build the docker image manually, and also automatically with my CI/CD (AzureDevOps). But both are producing the same error.
I checked for any change in GIT history... nothing.

Here is the DockerFile I use

```
### >>> GLOBALS
ARG ENVIRONMENT="Production"
ARG PROJECT="SmartPixel.SoCloze.Web"

# debian buster - AMD64
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

### >>> IMPORTS
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PROJECT

ARG NUGET_CACHE=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
ARG NUGET_FEED=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

# Copy sources
COPY src/ /app/src
ADD common.props /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install /app/src/SmartPixel.Core.Blazor/

# Installs the required dependencies on top of the base image
# Publish a self-contained image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev && dotnet dev-certs https --clean;\
    dotnet dev-certs https && dotnet dev-certs https --trust;\
    dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 -c Debug -o out src/${PROJECT};

# Execute

# Start a new image from aspnet runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS runtime

### >>> IMPORTS
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PROJECT

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:80;https://+:443;https://+:44390" 
ENV PROJECT="${PROJECT}.dll"

# Make logs a volume for persistence
VOLUME /app/Logs

# App directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy our build from the previous stage in /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg libgdiplus libc6-dev

# Ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 44390

# Execute
ENTRYPOINT dotnet ${PROJECT}
```

What is strange is that old images (> 1-month-old) are all working, but not when I rebuild them.

Here is also the docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/mycorp/socloze.web:1.1.1040
    volumes:
     - keys-vol:/root/.aspnet
     - logs-vol:/app/Logs
     - sitemap-vol:/data/sitemap/
    networks:
     - haproxy-net
     - socloze-net
    configs:
     -
      source: socloze-web-conf
      target: /app/appsettings.json
    logging:
      driver: json-file
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
         - node.role == manager
networks:
  haproxy-net:
    external: true
  socloze-net:
    external: true
volumes:
  keys-vol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      device: /data/socloze/web/keys
      o: bind
      type: none
  logs-vol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      device: /data/socloze/web/logs
      o: bind
      type: none
  sitemap-vol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      device: /data/sitemap
      o: bind
      type: none
configs:
  socloze-web-conf:
    external: true
```

What can be the cause if:

- old images are working perfectly
- new images are producing this error
- no code change, no change in the 'DockerFile'
- the OS is Debian, the Docker images system is Ubuntu

Do you have any idea? I'm searching for weeks about a solution!

Comment: did one of your base images change\update in this time span? also, I'm sure you've really hard but it would help us help you if you included every nessaccery code piece like site code, configuration, dockerfile, etc...

Comment: As certificates expire... maybe a new one is needed or was created and needs to be trusted - as the error message states

Comment: The certificate that cause the issue, seems to be the one generated by the command ''dotnet dev-certs https" in the docker file (it is my understanding). The other one, seems to work because it work with the older images. (Btw, I have try removing the "... --clean" command, but it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a couple more environment variable and might also have to mount a certificate volume:

Environment Variables and their values:

```
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
```

and volumes:

```
- ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

depending on how you plan to add these env variables and mount volumes like `dokcer run` or through docker-compose you will have to play with the adding double quotes to the parameter lists and right spots.

Comment: Thx, but there is the certificate handled by haproxy and the browsers. The problem here is between the docker image and haproxy. In the DockerFile we use "dotnet dev-certs https" to generate dev certificates for this, it should be enough and should work. Right ?(or not)